# How should be understood the expression " taking the differentials of both sides of an equation". ( Taking differentials VS differentiating)

Tags: calculus, soft-question

In a basic book, more precisely in the chapter dealing with special relativity, the author aims at showing how is derived this theorem of relativistic dynamics

$ K= mc^2 - m_0 c^2$.

At one point of the derivation, he uses the relativistic expression of mass, that he reexpresses as : $ m^2c^2-m^2u^2=m_0^2c^2$ ( where $u$ is the velocity of a particle in a given inertial reference frame).

Then he says : " ***taking the differentials of both sides*** of this expression we obtain :

$2mc^2dm-m^22udu-u^2 2mdm=0$"

I've already heard about the differential of a function of $x$, defined as the linear change in $y$ for an infinitesimal change in $x$.

What I don't understand here is : with respect to what variables are these differentials taken? Is it allowed to take differentials with respect to various different variables ( if the equation is to remain valid?) Is " taking the differentials" the same thing as " differentiating"?

below, solved problem 8.21 [image]

Comment: They're all implicitly differentiated with respect to presumably $t$ in this case. The $\mathrm{dt}$ is multiplied out. Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$They are being differentiated with respect to time $t$. Rewritten, we have

$$ c^2 \cdot m(u(t))^2 - m(u(t))^2 \cdot u(t)^2 = m_0^2 c^2$$

(Note that this follows as mass is dependent on velocity.) Trivially the right-hand side differentiates to zero, being constant. Then differentiating and applying the chain rule repeatedly, we have

$$\frac{\d}{\d t} c^2 m(u(t))^2 = 2c^2\cdot  m(u(t)) \cdot \underbrace{m'(u(t)) \cdot u'(t)}_{\displaystyle =\frac{\d}{\d t} m(u(t))} \tag 1$$

and

\begin{align*}
\frac{\d}{\d t} m(u(t))^2 u(t)^2 
&= 2\cdot  m(u(t)) \cdot m'(u(t)) \cdot u'(t)\cdot  u(t)^2 \\
&\;\;\; + 2\cdot  m(u(t))^2\cdot  u(t) \cdot u'(t) \tag 2
\end{align*}

Equivalently framed, we have

$$2c^2 m \, \d m \tag{1'}$$

and

$$2mu^2 \, \d m + 2m^2 u \, \d u \tag{2'}$$

respectively, and these lead to the desired expression.

---

> Is " taking the differentials" the same thing as " differentiating"?

Almost. Let $y=f(x)$. Then the differentials $\d y, \d x$ are defined as being such that $\d y = f'(x) \, \d x$, at least when first introduced in elementary calculus classes.

For instance, notice that if you multiply $(1)$ and $(2)$ by $\d t$, you basically get your result. (Not always justifiable, of course, but as a rule of thumb, it's not too bad.)

You can think of $\d f$ as being "an incredibly small change in $f$" - like a $\Delta f$, but specifically geared to be super small.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eevee Trainer !

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you don't need a variable with which to take a differential with respect to.  You can take a differential, essentially, "by itself".  This sort of operation is done quite a bit in physics.

There does, indeed, need to be *something* connecting the variables for this to work, but you needn't actually know what it is.  Just knowing that they are tied together in some vague metaphysical sense is sufficient.